# Can't use rails command getting "dyld[22076]: missing symbol called zsh: abort rails db:create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I switched intel to M2 chip.

I moved data using time machine then can't use rails command any more.

I tried:

①reinstall homebrew,xcode-select

②change homebrew path. the path is export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"

I don't use `arch -x86_64 zsh`

homebrew and rbenv are fine.

The only rails command doesn't work.

Comment: what version of rails? what version of ruby?

Comment: ruby version is 3.0.0